# How to get this jquery postal code address retriever working with cURL?

Tags: php, jquery, curl

The code below works, but then when i publish the page, i get the cross domain not allowed error... people here told me to use cURL, but i tried and cant see to fit the cURL code to do that....

Can someone enlighten the thing for me? keep in mind that this is my first touch with cURL

Thank you in advance

(the page is php)

```
$(function(){
           /**
            * act when the postal code field gets blur
            */
           $("#cad_cep").blur(function(){
               /**
                * Retrieve the value on postal code field
                * use replace to erase non-numeric inputs
                * with a regular expression
                */
               var cep = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/, ''); 

              //Creates the variable with the json url appending the postal code
             var url = 'https://correiosapi.apphb.com/cep/'+cep;

              /**
              * using $.getJSON to get the request return;
              */

              $.getJSON(url, function(json){
                           //giving the return values to the other form inputs
                           $("#cad_endereco").val(json.logradouro);
                           $("#cad_bairro").val(json.bairro);
                           $("#cad_cidade").val(json.cidade);
                           $("#cad_uf").val(json.estado);

                       }).fail(function(){
                        //if it fails, do something
                   });

           });
       });
```

Comment: The client needs to send an ajax request to your server to get the postal code. Your server then makes an http request via curl to `correiosapi.apphb.com` and responds to the ajax request with the curl call result.

Comment: Kind of get it... so i make a intermediate page to fetch the data, then use it on my form page so i would get "cross domain not allowed" ?

Comment: I provided an answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client needs to send an ajax request to your server to get the postal code. Your server then makes an HTTPS request via curl to `correiosapi.apphb.com` and responds to the ajax request with the curl call result.

```
$(function(){
    $("#cad_cep").blur(function(){
        var cep = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/, '');
        // make a request to your own server
        $.getJSON('/getpostal.php?cep=' + cep, function(json){
            // this json comes from your own server.
            $("#cad_endereco").val(json.logradouro);
            $("#cad_bairro").val(json.bairro);
            $("#cad_cidade").val(json.cidade);
            $("#cad_uf").val(json.estado);
         }).fail(function(){
             //if it fails, do something
         });
    });
});
```

On the root of your own server make a file called **getpostal.php**

```
<?php
// make a curl call to get the postal code data
$ch = curl_init('https://correiosapi.apphb.com/cep/' . $_GET['cep']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
// set the content type and echo the curl response.
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json;
```

I won't guarantee this will work but it should get you started.

Comment: oh. my. god. It worked!! This was something i thought that would never happen! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `$.ajax()` instead of `$.getJSON()` setting `crossDomain` option to `true` like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(json){
                       //giving the return values to the other form inputs
                       $("#cad_endereco").val(json.logradouro);
                       $("#cad_bairro").val(json.bairro);
                       $("#cad_cidade").val(json.cidade);
                       $("#cad_uf").val(json.estado);

                   },
    error: function(){
                    //if it fails, do something
               }
});
```

Comment: The 'dataType' is missing a comma... but i still get 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'